# When converting MS Words table to LaTeX, Overfull \hbox 2308.26472 too wide warning always shows up

Tags: tables, conversion, page

I'm writing my Bachelor thesis with the classic thesis style template. and my thesis has a lot of big and long use case tables. I made the tables on MS words first and then convert it to LaTeX with the latex-tables.com generator. But the tables result is too wide for my page with a resulting overfull \hbox 2308.26472 warning. I think it's because the cell content isn't split to multiline like my word tables. I am really new to LaTeX and have tried searching for different answers here but I can't still find it.

here is the code snippet:

```
\documentclass{paper}
\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom


 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{colortbl}


\begin{table}
\centering
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\begin{tabular}{!{\color{black}\vrule}l!{\color{black}\vrule}l!{\color{black}\vrule}l!{\color{black}\vrule}} 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{!{\color{black}\vrule}l!{\color{black}\vrule}}{Use Case Title}              & Vessel Arrival Times Prediction                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{!{\color{black}\vrule}l!{\color{black}\vrule}}{Use Case Description}        & The shipping vessel arrival times can be accurately predicted by analyzing several relevant variables ranging from the ship’s data to weather and tidal condition at the area of the terminal. The terminal can then detect delay in real-time and efficiently plan the terminal operation according to the prediction.                                                                                                                                                                        \\ 
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{Big Data Characteristics} & Data Source                                     & AIS Data: Ship type, length, width, draught, speed, heading, port of destination. VTS data: radar, traffic signals, video surveillance, radio communication system. Sensors: weather, tidal, temperature.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      \\ 
\cline{2-3}
                                          & Volume                                          & To have a very precise prediction than a broad and large dataset is required.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\cline{2-3}
                                          & Velocity                                        & Depends on the data source. If it is an existing historical data like the ship type,~width, length, port of destination, then it can be batch loaded. If it is a data that need real-time processing like the data from sensors, GPS, and radar then the data need to be streamed.                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ 
\cline{2-3}
                                          & Variety                                         & There are various data source in this use case so a data lake is required for data integration.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ 
\cline{2-3}
                                          & Veracity and Data Quality                       & Any external data like the data from sensor needs data cleansing because the data quality is not enough to pipeline it direct to the model. The data from AIS needs to be decoded from its NMEA format first. Internal structured data from the terminal has good quality. This will of course need the existence of system that ensure good quality internal data. But to be sure the internal data should also pass a cleansing process even though it can skip some of the cleansing stage  \\ 
\cline{2-3}
                                          & Value                                           & The cargo container and ship data is highly valuable for the container terminal since it is also government data that need to be collected and safely kept for at least 10 years.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Big Data Science}         & Presentation and Implementation                 & A prediction of vessel arrival time and also a visualization of said ship movement pattern needs to be presented to the container terminal operator. In the event of bad weather and tidal condition around the quayside area, the system will then analyze and provide the terminal operator with the best prediction outcomes to save time and cost.                                                                                                                                         \\ 
\cline{2-3}
                                          & Data Types                                      & Existing historical data from internal system are structured data. Any external data like radar, GPS is unstructured data.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     \\ 
\cline{2-3}
                                          & Data Analytics                                  & A predictive analytical model is required to accurately predict the vessel arrival times. A classification and regression tree model can be trained in order to make a precise prediction of the ship arrival. The model needs to also take various relevant variables and parameters into account and train themselves based on these parameters. A modified framework of case based reasoning could be utilized to detect ship’s delay early by processing satellite AIS data in real-time.  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Privacy and Security}     & Specific Personal Data (SPD) used               & No                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ 
\cline{2-3}
                                          & Highly sensitive data used                      & Some of classified government data could be used in this Use Case                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \\ 
\cline{2-3}
                                          & Governance, Compliance and Audit                & Indonesia classify export and import by using the Harmonized System of nomenclature and codification of goods.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ 
\hline
Organizational Requirements               & External Cooperation Partners                   & The manufacturer of the sensor and radar system. External data provider and external shipping company. Indonesia Directorate General of Customs excise for the custom inspection.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{!{\color{black}\vrule}l!{\color{black}\vrule}}{Other Big Data Challenges}   & Because there are so many input variables and parameter, it requires a long time to train the predictive model. The lack of reliable information and forecasting cause uncertainties and disruption on the terminal operation.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I am sorry if for asking a basic question like this, I am really new with LaTex table making. and one other question I would like to ask is that my tables in words sometimes need two pages just to display it, will LaTeX automatically extend my tables to following pages?

I thank you guys kindly for your help and answer.

Comment: Use longtable package @Vailendra Satriani

Comment: Please make your example complilable

Comment: Which `\documentclass` you are using? (You forgot to add it to your MWE)

Comment: @Zarko ah yeah sorry zarko it should be paper, I was copy-pasting from the classic thesis style template.

Comment: @daleif ah yes I'm sorry daleif, it should be better now.

Comment: @Biki Teron so instead of tabular I should use longtable? thank you Biki i will try it.

Comment: I would use four separate tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use three separate `table` environments, with four separate tables, grouped by the subtitles.

```latex
\documentclass[
  openright,
  titlepage,
  numbers=noenddot,
  headinclude,
  %twoside,
  %1headlines,
  footinclude=true,
  cleardoublepage=empty,
  %abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
  BCOR=5mm,
  paper=a4,
  fontsize=11pt
  ngerman,
  american,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,caption}

\captionsetup[table]{position=top,belowskip=\bigskipamount}

\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\begin{table}[htp]

\caption[Vessel arrival times prediction.]{%
  Vessel arrival times prediction. 
  The shipping vessel arrival times can be accurately predicted by analyzing
  several relevant variables ranging from the ship’s data to weather and tidal
  condition at the area of the terminal. The terminal can then detect delay in
  real-time and efficiently plan the terminal operation according to the prediction.}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  @{}
  >{\raggedright\hsize=0.5\hsize}X
  >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\itshape Big Data Characteristics} \\
\midrule
Use Case Title & Vessel Arrival Times Prediction \\ 
\midrule
Data Source &
  AIS Data: Ship type, length, width, draught, speed, heading, port of destination. 
  VTS data: radar, traffic signals, video surveillance, radio communication system.
  Sensors: weather, tidal, temperature.
\\ 
\addlinespace
Volume &
  To have a very precise prediction than a broad and large dataset is required.
\\ 
\addlinespace
Velocity &
  Depends on the data source. If it is an existing historical data like the ship type,
  width, length, port of destination, then it can be batch loaded. If it is a data that
  need real-time processing like the data from sensors, GPS, and radar then the data
  need to be streamed.
\\ 
\addlinespace
Variety &
  There are various data source in this use case so a data lake is required for data 
  integration.
\\ 
\addlinespace
Veracity and Data Quality &
  Any external data like the data from sensor needs data cleansing because the data
  quality is not enough to pipeline it direct to the model. The data from AIS needs
  to be decoded from its NMEA format first. Internal structured data from the terminal
  has good quality. This will of course need the existence of system that ensure good
  quality internal data. But to be sure the internal data should also pass a cleansing
  process even though it can skip some of the cleansing stage
\\ 
\addlinespace
Value &
  The cargo container and ship data is highly valuable for the container terminal since
  it is also government data that need to be collected and safely kept for at least
  10~years.
\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\ContinuedFloat

\caption{Vessel arrival times prediction.}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  @{}
  >{\raggedright\hsize=0.5\hsize}X
  >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\itshape Big Data Science} \\
\midrule     
Use Case Title & Vessel Arrival Times Prediction \\
\midrule
Presentation and Implementation &
  A prediction of vessel arrival time and also a visualization of said ship movement
  pattern needs to be presented to the container terminal operator. In the event of
  bad weather and tidal condition around the quayside area, the system will then
  analyze and provide the terminal operator with the best prediction outcomes to save
  time and cost.
\\ 
\addlinespace
Data Types &
  Existing historical data from internal system are structured data. Any external data
  like radar, GPS is unstructured data.
\\ 
\addlinespace
Data Analytics &
  A predictive analytical model is required to accurately predict the vessel arrival
  times. A classification and regression tree model can be trained in order to make a
  precise prediction of the ship arrival. The model needs to also take various relevant
  variables and parameters into account and train themselves based on these parameters.
  A modified framework of case based reasoning could be utilized to detect ship’s delay
  early by processing satellite AIS data in real-time.
\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\ContinuedFloat

\caption{Vessel arrival times prediction.}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  @{}
  >{\raggedright\hsize=0.5\hsize}X
  >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\itshape Privacy and Security} \\
\midrule
Use Case Title & Vessel Arrival Times Prediction \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
Specific Personal Data (SPD) used  &
  No
\\ 
\addlinespace
Highly sensitive data used &
  Some of classified government data could be used in this Use Case
\\ 
\addlinespace
Governance, Compliance and Audit &
  Indonesia classify export and import by using the Harmonized System of nomenclature
  and codification of goods.
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  @{}
  >{\raggedright\hsize=0.5\hsize}X
  >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\itshape Organizational Requirements} \\
\midrule
Use Case Title & Vessel Arrival Times Prediction \\
\midrule
External Cooperation Partners &
  The manufacturer of the sensor and radar system. External data provider and external
  shipping company. Indonesia Directorate General of Customs excise for the custom inspection.
\\
\midrule
Other Big Data Challenges &
  Because there are so many input variables and parameter, it requires a long time
  to train the predictive model. The lack of reliable information and forecasting
  cause uncertainties and disruption on the terminal operation.
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you mate. this helps me so much. I hope you have a nice day :)

Comment: @VailendraSatriani You're very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

In case you prefer presenting all the information in one table, you could make use of `landscape` and `xltabular` as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{paper}

\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{>{\RaggedRight}p{2cm}>{\RaggedRight}p{3cm}X} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Use Case Title}              & Vessel Arrival Times Prediction                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Use Case Description}        & The shipping vessel arrival times can be accurately predicted by analyzing several relevant variables ranging from the ship’s data to weather and tidal condition at the area of the terminal. The terminal can then detect delay in real-time and efficiently plan the terminal operation according to the prediction.                                                                                                                                                                        \\ 
\midrule
Big Data Characteristics & Data Source                                     & AIS Data: Ship type, length, width, draught, speed, heading, port of destination. VTS data: radar, traffic signals, video surveillance, radio communication system. Sensors: weather, tidal, temperature.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      \\ 
\addlinespace
                                          & Volume                                          & To have a very precise prediction than a broad and large dataset is required.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\addlinespace
                                          & Velocity                                        & Depends on the data source. If it is an existing historical data like the ship type,~width, length, port of destination, then it can be batch loaded. If it is a data that need real-time processing like the data from sensors, GPS, and radar then the data need to be streamed.                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ 
\addlinespace
                                          & Variety                                         & There are various data source in this use case so a data lake is required for data integration.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ 
\addlinespace
                                          & Veracity and Data Quality                       & Any external data like the data from sensor needs data cleansing because the data quality is not enough to pipeline it direct to the model. The data from AIS needs to be decoded from its NMEA format first. Internal structured data from the terminal has good quality. This will of course need the existence of system that ensure good quality internal data. But to be sure the internal data should also pass a cleansing process even though it can skip some of the cleansing stage  \\ 
\addlinespace
                                          & Value                                           & The cargo container and ship data is highly valuable for the container terminal since it is also government data that need to be collected and safely kept for at least 10 years.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \\ 
\midrule
Big Data Science         & Presentation and Implementation                 & A prediction of vessel arrival time and also a visualization of said ship movement pattern needs to be presented to the container terminal operator. In the event of bad weather and tidal condition around the quayside area, the system will then analyze and provide the terminal operator with the best prediction outcomes to save time and cost.                                                                                                                                         \\ 
\addlinespace
                                          & Data Types                                      & Existing historical data from internal system are structured data. Any external data like radar, GPS is unstructured data.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     \\ 
\addlinespace
                                          & Data Analytics                                  & A predictive analytical model is required to accurately predict the vessel arrival times. A classification and regression tree model can be trained in order to make a precise prediction of the ship arrival. The model needs to also take various relevant variables and parameters into account and train themselves based on these parameters. A modified framework of case based reasoning could be utilized to detect ship’s delay early by processing satellite AIS data in real-time.  \\ 
\midrule
Privacy and Security     & Specific Personal Data (SPD) used               & No                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ 
\addlinespace
                                          & Highly sensitive data used                      & Some of classified government data could be used in this Use Case                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \\ 
\addlinespace
                                          & Governance, Compliance and Audit                & Indonesia classify export and import by using the Harmonized System of nomenclature and codification of goods.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ 
\midrule
Organi\-zational Requirements               & External Cooperation Partners                   & The manufacturer of the sensor and radar system. External data provider and external shipping company. Indonesia Directorate General of Customs excise for the custom inspection.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Other Big Data Challenges}   & Because there are so many input variables and parameter, it requires a long time to train the predictive model. The lack of reliable information and forecasting cause uncertainties and disruption on the terminal operation.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\
\bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahh this is also usable for my other table. thanks mate :) this helps me a lot :)